# Can you rollback the firmware to an earlier version on a Super Slim 500GB PS3?

Tags: ps3

Why does my Sony PlayStation 3 Super Slim (500GB) only display the option to install/download version 4.66 or later - there does not appear to any option to download an earlier firmware than this.

I have already tried restarting it but I'm only given the option to install/download version 4.66 or later. What's the problem? Why are earlier versions not available?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: you would have to factory reset the playstation and download a custom version of the firmware. You will not be able to play most games online after doing this, why do you want to rollback? Is it to "jailbreak" the playstation by any chance.

Answer (score 2):

Sony does not allow downgrading firmware versions, you can only install the newest version because that is all they offer.